# Can I render XAML or HTML inside a panel in Silverlight? Using RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

Actually, I want to display a string of HTML inside my Silverlight application. I haven't found any solutions that work. I read there is a control that can do this, but it only works if the SL application is out of browser, which is not an option for me. So I thought I could convert the HTML to XAML using Microsoft's example classes found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129.aspx

And then have a RichTextBox control, whose Xaml property I would set to the XAML string. However, this throws an ArgumentException with the text "Value" (not too helpful). It seems that when you set this Xaml property, it's quite picky what would qualify as acceptable XAML. My HTML isn't too fancy. It has several tables (tr and td elements). Here's an example of XAML that does work to set to the RichTextBox's XAML property:

```
<Section xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><Paragraph>Blah</Paragraph></Section>
```

Here's an example of the XAML that I tried to set to the RichTextBox's XAML property that does NOT work:

```
<FlowDocument xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"><Table></Table></FlowDocument>
```

I tried replacing "FlowDocument" with "Section", and that didn't work either. It doesn't like the "Table" element in the XAML.

Are there any other ways to accomplish what I want to do?
thanks

Comment: You can easily display any XAML or HTML strings in a `TextBlock`. No escaping needed.

Comment: What do you mean? If I set a TextBlock's Text property to the HTML or XAML string, it just displays the raw markup. It doesn't convert it like a web browser.

Comment: May I suggest you change your question (and particularly the title) to explicitly state that you want to **render** HTML instead of just "display XAML or HTML strings"